# Different results with map function

Tags: r, purrr

I am getting different results with the *map* function from the library *purr*. Here is the following code used in Hadley's book, R for data science. Why is this?

**code1**

```
models1 <- mtcars %>% split(.$cyl) %>% 
  map(function(df) lm(mpg ~ wt, data=mtcars))

models1 %>% 
  map(summary) %>% 
  map_dbl(~.$r.squared)
```

**code1- result**

```
        4         6         8 
0.5086326 0.4645102 0.4229655
```

**code2**

```
models2 <- mtcars %>% split(.$cyl) %>% 
  map(~lm(mpg ~ wt, data=.))

models2 %>% 
  map(summary) %>% 
  map_dbl(~.$r.squared)
```

**code2-result**

```
        4         6         8 
0.7528328 0.7528328 0.7528328
```

Comment: For **code1**, `lm` is being run on the _entire_ `mtcars` for each element of the list, while for **code2**, you are feeding `.` into the `data` argument, so an `lm` is run on each `cyl` group. Try `lm(mpg ~ wt, data=df)` for **code1** and it should give you the same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing the entire dataset `mtcars` to the `lm()` function in code-1 instead of passing in `df` which you declare in your function definition in `map(function(df) ...)` if you change `mtcars` to `df` your problem is fixed

```r
library(tidyverse)

models1 <- mtcars %>% split(.$cyl) %>% 
  map(function(df) lm(mpg ~ wt, data=df))

models1 %>% 
  map(summary) %>% 
  map_dbl(~.$r.squared)
#>         4         6         8 
#> 0.5086326 0.4645102 0.4229655

models2 <- mtcars %>% split(.$cyl) %>% 
  map(~lm(mpg ~ wt, data=.))

models2 %>% 
  map(summary) %>% 
  map_dbl(~.$r.squared)
#>         4         6         8 
#> 0.5086326 0.4645102 0.4229655
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>